# How to dynamically generate Pipes in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, iteration, pipe

I'm building a data augmentation pipeline using dataframes. I've created a function, `h3_int`, that takes an int input and appends a column of hex values to the dataframe. Here's the implementation of `h3_int`:

```
from h3.unstable import vect
def h3_int(df, level):
    df['h3_' + str(level)] = vect.geo_to_h3(df.lat.values, df.lng.values, level).tolist()
    return df
```

`df` is comprised of a `lng` and `lat` column:

```
    lat lng
0   43.64617    -79.42451
1   43.64105    -79.37628
2   43.66724    -79.41598
3   43.69602    -79.45468
4   43.66890    -79.32592
... ... ...
9515    36.10644    -115.16711
9516    36.00814    -115.17496
9517    36.10711    -115.16607
9518    36.03119    -115.05352
9519    36.13554    -115.11541
```

Simple usage of `h3_int`:

```
df.pipe(h3_int, 8)
```

Since the input is dynamic, I'd like to dynamically generate the pipes as well, but I've been having difficulty implementing this.

The code,

```
(df.pipe(h3_int, i) for i in range(8, 10))
```

returns:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fd4858557b0>
```

While,

```
(df.pipe((h3_int, i) for i in range(8, 10)))
```

raises an exception:

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

**What's the correct method for implementing dynamic pipes in pandas?** Unfortunately I've found the documentation and Stack Overflow lacking in answers.

Comment: What's `h3_int`?

Comment: Also, please add a sample of your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension inside of parentheses returns a `generator`, which is not indexable, as the error message indicates. Instead, you can use square brackets to create a list, which *is* indexable:

```py
>>> [df.pipe(h3_int, i) for i in range(8, 9)][0]
        lat        lng                h3_8
0  43.64617  -79.42451  613256717813153791
1  43.64105  -79.37628  613256717559398399
2  43.66724  -79.41598  613256718316470271
3  43.69602  -79.45468  613256716607291391
4  43.66890  -79.32592  613256718037549055
5  36.10644 -115.16711  613220086766895103
6  36.00814 -115.17496  613220073288499199
7  36.10711 -115.16607  613220086766895103
8  36.03119 -115.05352  613220075656183807
9  36.13554 -115.11541  613220087052107775
```

Note that `df` was modified in place because your function `h3_int` does not copy it before modifying it. That's not bad, it's just something to keep in mind.

Comment: excellent thanks for all the help today!

Comment: You're welcome! I think it's fun helping a user over and over again with questions in one day :D